# Find $f$ using equation involving real and imaginary part

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f=u+iv$ is differentiable in the entire complex plane. The real and imaginary parts of $f$ are related by $au(x,y)+bv(x,y)+c=0$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a$ and $b$ are not simultaneously zero. Find $f$.

My attempt: Differentiate the equation with respect to $x$ and $y$. Then we obtain two equations $$au_x+bv_x=0$$ $$au_y+bv_y=0$$

Since $f$ is differentiable, by Cauchy Riemann equation, $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$. By substituting the CR-equations into the two equations above, we have $$av_y+bv_x=0$$ $$au_y+bu_x=0$$

Then I stuck here. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write down everyting wrt $\;u\;$ , say:

$$\begin{align*}au_x-bu_y&=0\\bu_x+au_y&=0\end{align*}$$

Now multiply the first equation by $\;a\;$ , the second one by $\;b\;$ and add them:

$$(a^2+b^2)u_x=0\implies u_x=0\;\text{(as we're given}\;\;a^2+b^2\neq0)$$

So $\;u\;$ is constant wrt $\;x\;$ ...etc. Go on, now.

Comment: So by doing the same thing to $v$, we have $v$ is a constant. Hence, $f$ is just a complex number. Correct?

Comment: @Idonknow , I don't know if we get the same for $\;v\;$... and for $\;u\;$ we *only* know, by my answer, that it is constant wrt $\;x\;$...what about wrt $\;y\;$ ?? This you must check.

Comment: Since $u_x=0$, we have $-bu_y=0=au_y$. Since $a$ and $b$ cannot simultaneously zero, $u_y=0$. Hence, $u$ is a constant.

Comment: Ok, @Idonknow : now you're advancing...:) What about $\;v=\;$ the imaginary part of the function?

Comment: Using the same logic, we have $v$ is a constant. Hence, $f$ is just a complex number.

Comment: A word of caution: this is not a word problem and thus you cannot say "following the same logic...", @Idonknow . What you can **show** is the problem's symmetric wrt both $\;u,v\;$ and thus...Are you sure it is symmetric, though? Because if you aren't then you better do the actual calculation: it's as easy as with $\;u\;$ .